# Using purrr::map to rename based on a pattern

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, rename, purrr

I've got a variable name pattern that is distinguishable to me but not because the information is encoded in the variable name. So, the variables I'm interested in all start with the same random alphanumieric nonsense and are followed by a _Number that relates to a type and a _time so they look like nonsense_#_# which translates to Variable_Type_Time. Type ranges from 1:3 and 3 periods of time 1,5,7.

Is there a way to functionally rename using purrr:: and some sort of regex to avoid making a one-at a time rename(asf_1_1 = `Var1 TypeA  Time1`, asf_1_2 = `Var1 TypeA  Time2`. etc)
PS. I'm planning on using backtick-formatted variable names but you don't have to for the suggestions.

Reproducible code for issue

```
    x <- c("_1_1",
       "_1_2",
       "_1_3",
       "_2_1",
       "_2_2",
       "_2_3",
       "_3_1",
       "_3_2",
       "_3_3",
       "_4_3")
paste0("asf",x)

test <- t(as_tibble(rnorm(10, 5.5, .35)))
colnames(test) <- paste0("asf",x)
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output? This sounds like a job for reshaping from wide-to-long first and then using e.g. `tidyr::separate` to automatically separate entries to create a type and time column.

Comment: To give a specific example: `library(tidyverse); test %>% as_tibble() %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% separate(name, c("nonsense", "type", "time"), sep = "_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous to me; is this what you're trying to do?

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- c("_1_1",
       "_1_2",
       "_1_3",
       "_2_1",
       "_2_2",
       "_2_3",
       "_3_1",
       "_3_2",
       "_3_3",
       "_4_3")
paste0("asf",x)

test <- t(as_tibble(rnorm(10, 5.5, .35)))
colnames(test) <- paste0("asf",x)

test_renamed <- as.data.frame(test) %>% 
  rename_with(~ sub("asf", "Var1 ", .x)) %>%
  rename_with(~ sub(" _", " Type", .x)) %>% 
  rename_with(~ sub("_", " Time", .x))

colnames(test_renamed)
#> [1] "Var1 Type1 Time1" "Var1 Type1 Time2" "Var1 Type1 Time3" "Var1 Type2 Time1"
#>[5] "Var1 Type2 Time2" "Var1 Type2 Time3" "Var1 Type3 Time1" "Var1 Type3 Time2"
#>[9] "Var1 Type3 Time3" "Var1 Type4 Time3"

test_renamed$`Var1 Type1 Time1`
#>[1] 5.868449
```

Comment: This was useful but I haven't been able to run several at once. For example `

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are in same format i.e `"_1_1", "_1_2", "_1_3", "_2_1", "_2_2",  "_2_3"` etc. then you can use `outer` to generate the column names.

```
Type <- 1:3
Time <- 1:3
colnames(test) <- paste('Var1', c(t(outer(paste0('Type', LETTERS[Type]), 
                        paste0('Time', Time), paste, sep = ' '))), sep = ' ')
test

#      Var1 TypeA Time1 Var1 TypeA Time2 Var1 TypeA Time3 Var1 TypeB Time1
#value         5.516318         5.772653         5.033264         5.858262
#      Var1 TypeB Time2 Var1 TypeB Time3 Var1 TypeC Time1 Var1 TypeC Time2
#value         5.370641         5.213774         5.270832          5.26579
#      Var1 TypeC Time3
#value          5.55312
```

I removed `"_4_3"` value from `x` for this example.